# Given an array, how to remove the white spaces before and after a single occuring colon & and make other multiple whitespaces turn into one?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Array example entry:

```
test : title=Diet    Coke
```

Becomes

```
test:title=Diet Coke
```

Comment: You mean colon, not semi-colon, right?

Comment: Will there always be exactly one space before and after the colon, or could there be, for example, no space before and one after?

Comment: There could be no space before and one after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach using regular expression handles just one string, but if you want to do an array, just iterate over the array and apply this to each string:

```
$target="test : title=Diet    Coke";
print_r(preg_replace('/\s*([\s:])\s*/','\1',$target));
```

Output:

```
test:title=Diet Coke
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regex guru, but this is the general idea:

```
$my_array = array('test : title=Diet    Coke');

function do_crazy_thing($string){
  $string = preg_replace('/  +/', ' ', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('/ : /', ':', $string);
  return $string;
}

$my_array = array_map('do_crazy_thing', $my_array);
```

EDIT: have just tested this and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $a as $k=>$v ) {
    $v     = preg_replace("`\s*:\s*`", ":", $v);
    $a[$k] = preg_replace("`\s*`", " ", $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the non regex way,

```
$string= "test : title=Diet    Coke";
$s = explode(":",$string);
$s[0]=trim($s[0]);
$s[1]=trim($s[1]);
print implode(":",$s);
```

Comment: And to compact the whitespace after the colon, replace the line $s[1]=trim($s[1]); with:

$s[1] = implode(" ", array_filter(array_map("trim",explode(" ",$s[1]))));

I'm in a computer lab and PHP isn't installed here, so I'm not sure if that'll actually work but hopefully you get the idea.